# Undo deletion: What books introduce someone (who never took any politics courses) to politics for the first time?

Tags: discussion

Can https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12793/6241 (unilaterally deleted by a moderator) please be reinstated, to enable me to try to emend it?

Answer (score 3):

The question got four down votes, got closed by three users and received two very low quality answers. It would be in your own interest to post a new question instead of editing the old.

But keep in mind that there were reasons why the question was so badly received. [Stack Exchange in general is no good place for shopping recommendations](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). What literature is relevant and what isn't is very opinion-based. *If* you decide to repost it, please at least try to define some objectively measureable criteria for what books you are looking for and what books you are not looking for.